# Print data into a while loop from a function

Tags: php

I have created a function to get data from a table.

Now I want to print the returned data into a table using a while loop.
Almost everything ok but when I call the function, it will print only the first row.

```
$usr = $_SESSION['MM_UID'];
function getData($leavetype,$eo, $usr)
{
    $get = "SELECT * FROM `leaveregister` WHERE employee = '$usr' AND `leaveType`='$leavetype' ";
    $getdata = mysqli_query($eo, $get);
    while($geta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata))
    {
        return($geta);
    }
}
echo '<strong>Annual Leaves</strong>';
echo '<table class="table basicTable"><thead><th>Leave Duration</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
$getb = getData('annual',$eo,$usr);
echo '<tr><td>'.$getb['leaveDays'].'</td><td>'.$getb['startDate'].'</td><td>'.$getb['endDate'].'</td><td>'.$getb['remarks'].'</td></tr>';

echo '<tr><strong></tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Please note : `$eo` is the database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while` loop :
Here is sample code :

```
$usr = $_SESSION['MM_UID'];
function getData($leavetype,$eo, $usr)
{
    $get = "SELECT * FROM `leaveregister` WHERE employee = '$usr' AND `leaveType`='$leavetype' ";
    $getdata = mysqli_query($eo, $get);
    return($getdata);
}
echo '<strong>Annual Leaves</strong>';
echo '<table class="table basicTable"><thead><th>Leave Duration</th><th>Start Date</th><th>End Date</th></thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
$getc = getData('annual',$eo,$usr);
while($getb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getc)){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$getb['leaveDays'].'</td><td>'.$getb['startDate'].'</td><td>'.$getb['endDate'].'</td><td>'.$getb['remarks'].'</td></tr>';
}

echo '<tr><strong></tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `getData` returns a single result. Let's fix that:

```
function getData($leavetype,$eo, $usr)
{
    $get = "SELECT * FROM `leaveregister` WHERE employee = '$usr' AND `leaveType`='$leavetype' ";
    $getdata = mysqli_query($eo, $get);
    $result = array();
    while($geta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata))
    {
        $result[] = $geta;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Now you can call it and loop through it to populate your table.

```
$results = getData('annual',$eo,$usr);
?>
<strong>Annual Leaves</strong>
<table class="table basicTable">
    <thead>
       <th>Leave Duration</th>
       <th>Start Date</th>
       <th>End Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php foreach($results as $getb) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$getb['leaveDays'].'</td><td>'.$getb['startDate'].'</td>
    <td>'.$getb['endDate'].'</td><td>'.$getb['remarks'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '<tr><strong></tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `foreach`:

```
 function getData($leavetype,$eo, $usr)
  {
    $get = "SELECT * FROM `leaveregister` WHERE employee = '$usr' AND `leaveType`='$leavetype' ";
    $getdata = mysqli_query($eo, $get);
     return $geta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata))         
  }



$getb = getData('annual',$eo,$usr);
$table = '';
foreach($getb as $b){
  $table .='<tr><td>'.$b['leaveDays'].'</td><td>';
  $table .=$b['startDate'].'</td><td>'.$b['endDate'].'</td>';
  $table .='<td>'.$b['remarks'].'</td></tr>';

 }
 echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here.

```
    while($geta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata))
        {
            return($geta); 
        }
        //return here enter code here
```

Try gathering all the data in some data structure (e.g array) and after the last iteration return variable.

Comment: What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You return your result without retrieving all data. Change your while statement, your problem will be solved.

```
$get = "SELECT * FROM `leaveregister` WHERE employee = '$usr' AND `leaveType`='$leavetype' ";
$result = array();
$getdata = mysqli_query($eo, $get);
while($geta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata))
{
    $result[] = $geta;
}
return $result;
```